# Rails new ERROR [Puma]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Steps to reproduce
rails new test_file

Expected rails to create the files and install the gemfile with no errors.

Actual behavior
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java.

Fetching puma 3.11.0
Installing puma 3.11.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

An error occurred while installing puma (3.11.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install puma -v '3.11.0' succeeds before bundling.

System configuration
Ruby version: 2.3.0
Rails version: 5.4.1
Puma version: 3.10.0

Comment: What operation system do you use?

Comment: Mac OS [High Sierra]is my operating system

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
gem install puma -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
bundle install #=> inside project
```

I don't know which OS you using

**For Windows**

Install [PUMA GEM](https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows)

**For MAC OS**

Install [PUMA GEM](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/783#issuecomment-141254723)

I think will help

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

1. install ruby with DevKit
2. gem install openssl -v 2.1.0
3. gem install puma